# VB 2010: Connect Application To an IP address

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to modify a program I have built in using VB 2010.
It is a Race Manager for Car Races.
I would like to connect my application to an IP address where the time and scoring sends out laptimes for each car and driver and the position of every car on track.
I know the IP address and the Port.
Any idea about the path i need to follow to be able to show the data from Time and scoring on my software correctly?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your question, but to connect to another computer you can try using sockets and I suppose this app you are doing is a client side (in Networking terms) because if its a server it would only listen for incoming connection requests so here is what I have used on my project.

I've installed Visual Basic 5.0 because I also use it to create unInstalled programs. So it came with a very nice tool called Winsock which I used to make my apps communicate with one another over network so it you have it on your computer I think your life will be a bit easier so you need to load it to VB 2010 as a tool and add it to your project then depending on how you want your app to connect to remote pc but I made mine connect on form load meaning on startup. So here is how you connect it using Winsock:

```
 ' Connecting
 AxWinsock1.RemoteHost = "The IP address you want to connect to here"
 AxWinsock1.RemotePort = "The Port you planing to use here"
 AxWinsock1.Connect()


  ' Send data
  AxWinsock1.SendData("Your data here")
```

There you are connecting and sending data.
Hope this answered your question.

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer, basically what I am trying to do is to receive data from a local network based on a Race track for race cars,  that is sending out lap times and position of the cars along the track. I mainly need to receive data, I guess another problem is the interpretation of the data i am receiving.